# Explanation of the Class Class-[desc] pattern used in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone provide some insight behind the use of the "class class-[desc]" pattern used in Bootstrap? For example navbar navbar-default, or glyphicon glyphicon-phone, etc. I am trying to learn Bootstrap and think it would help me remember things if I understood the reasons behind it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not unique to Bootstrap, it's a fairly common way of naming parent-child relationships.  Essentially, we do this to specify that the [parent] css class can have children with classes [parent]-[child].

Here's a pretty good article about it:  http://thesassway.com/advanced/modular-css-naming-conventions

Comment: Bootstrap's CSS is referred to as OOCSS, Object Oriented CSS. 

Here's an intro: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/.